# Node.js Change stdio of already running child process (to unref it)

Tags: node.js

I trying to figure out how to do the code below, but after a process has already been launched:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process')

const subprocess = spawn('top', {
  stdio: 'ignore'
})

subprocess.unref()
```

The reason is I'm using a library that launches a child process (puppeteer), and they do give access to the child process created, so I can use `.unref()` but I can't pass the `stdio: 'ignore'` options, which seems to be necessary in order to unref and have the node program exit after it is finished.